# Get a specific percent of a specific number

Tags: c#

So, I have two numbers, lets say I have 97 and 32.

I need to get 97% of 32, which would be 31.04.

In code, I have these variables

```
int amountFree = 32;
int percentToGet = 97;
```

What would be the formula to calculate a specific percent of a specific number?

It's not as simple as that though as I wont always know the values.

Comment: Do you know the definition of percent?

Comment: Yes, to get a certain amount of a value. I'm just asking for the formula to calculate it.

Comment: For 97% you would be getting 97 hundredths of a value. Does that make it easier?

Comment: This is getting the percent of how much a smaller number is of the bigger number, how is that even close to what I want to do? @MartinSmith

Comment: True, but tbh it shows you how to do basic maths operations in C#. You should be able to work it out from there.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It's a math question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double original = 32;
            double percentOf = 97;

            double total = original * percentOf / 100;

            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
```

I'm assuming this is a console application but the formula should be the same for the calculation you need.